# Placing ships in tkinter-based Battleship game

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm making a Battleship game using Python and Tkinter for GUI but I'm having some difficulties when it comes to the placement of the ships.

I'm using the random library (as `rd`) but there are 2 problems in my code:

1. The code only places one squared "ships" instead of varying from 1-5 depending on the length of each ship.
2. I can't prevent the ships from accumulating (being on top of each other).

Here is the function:

```
def place_boats(self):
    possible_coordinates = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    possible_directions = ["horizontal","vertical"]
    direction = rd.choice(possible_directions)
    for i in range(5):
        if direction == "horizontal":
            row = 0
            column = rd.choice(possible_coordinates)
        else:
            row = rd.choice(possible_coordinates)
        size = 1
        # self.board_status is an array composed of zeros and ones represent the ships
        for j in range(size):
            self.board_status[row+i][column] = 1
        size += 1
```

Comment: You don't use `j` in your second loop.

Comment: if `direction == "vertical"` then `column` is not defined.

Comment: Thanks I just noticed the mistakes, which are quite dumb but I think I'm too sleep-deprived to notice them. Thanks anyway!